# NDSolve with one parameter

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

This is a copyable minimal example to illustrate the problem that occours when I include one parameter `U` into a differential equation which I want to solve with `NDSolve`. If I do not include a parameter into my differential equation, the following code works just fine to solve the equation, and evaluates the solution to the equation at some point:

```
ClearAll[H, v, es, eiginst, sol, hope, newhope]

H[t_] := {{0, 1}, {1, t}}
v[t_] := Table[Subscript[v, i][t], {i, 1, 2}] 
es[t_] := Eigensystem[N[(H[t])]]
eiginst[t_] := Sort[Transpose[es[t]]]

sol = NDSolve[LogicalExpand[
         I*v'[t] == H[t].v[t] && v[0] == eiginst[0][[1]][[2]]], 
         v[t], {t, 0, 10}];

hope[t_] := Evaluate[v[t] /. sol]
hope[2]
(* {-0.215432 - 0.94635 I, 0.0773099 + 0.228111 I}} *)
```

However, if I include one parameter `U` into the exact same code I get errors, which I do not understand since it is the same code:

```
ClearAll[H, v, es, eiginst, sol, hope, newhope]

H[t_, U_] := U*{{0, 1}, {1, t}}
v[t_] := Table[Subscript[v, i][t], {i, 1, 2}] 
es[t_, U_] := Eigensystem[N[(H[t, U])]]
eiginst[t_, U_] := Sort[Transpose[es[t, U]]]

sol[U_] := NDSolve[LogicalExpand[
              I*v'[t] == H[t, U].v[t] && v[0] ==eiginst[0, U][[1]][[2]]], 
              v[t], {t, 0, 10}];

newhope[t_, U_] := Evaluate[v[t] /. sol[U]]
newhope[2, 1]
```

> NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0.`. >>
>
> ReplaceAll::reps: ... >>
>
> NDSolve::dsvar: ... >>
>
> ReplaceAll::reps: .. >>

Comment: Use `ParametricNDSolve` instead of `NDSolve`

Comment: Thank you! But will the runtime of ParametricNDSolve be the same? This is just a minimal example. In the end I want to include multiple parameters and the dimensions of the vectors and matrices will be very large.

Comment: I can get ParametricNDSolve to work in a simple example, but when I apply it to my problem It wont solve the equation. I am really frustrated, since I have been stuck on this problem for almost 2 days.

Comment: I have posted how you might solve your sample problem with `ParametricNDSolveValue` (a variant of `ParametricNDSolve`).  It is no slower than creating a function that, in effect, replicates `ParametricNDSolve` and may be more reliable and convenient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problems of the sort described typically are treated with `ParametricNDSolve`.

```
ClearAll[v, H, hope, newhope, sol, es, eiginst]
H[t_, U_] := U*{{0, 1}, {1, t}}
v[t_] := Table[Subscript[v, i][t], {i, 1, 2}] 
es[t_, U_] := Eigensystem[N[(H[t, U])]];
eiginst[t_, U_] := Sort[Transpose[es[t, U]]]
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[LogicalExpand[I*v'[t] == H[t, U].v[t] && 
    v[0] == eiginst[0, U][[1]][[2]]], v[t], {t, 0, 10}, {U}];
newhope[u_][t0_] := sol[u] /. t -> t0
```

Then, for instance,

```
newhope[1][2]
(* {-0.304667 - 1.33834 I, 0.109333 + 0.322597 I} *)
```

Comment: Thank you alot! Your answer solves the minimal problem. The only issue I have is, that it seems to me, that the eigenvector eiginst[0,U] which occours as initial condition in the ParametricNDSolveValue will be calculated universally for the parameter U, and only later the parameter is inserted. But for large matrices calculating the eigenvectors universally in dependence of the parameter U is impossible. Do you now how to solve this issue?

Comment: @Falafel  I would need to see an example to address this last issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can also keep `NDSolve` in the second code, but then you need to change the two last lines

```
newhope[t_, U_] := Evaluate[v[t] /. sol[U]]
newhope[2, 1]
```

to

```
newhope[t_, U_] := v[t] /. sol[U]
newhope[t, 1] /. t -> 2
```

You will end up with the same output as the first code.

The issue is that by doing `Evaluate[v[t] /. sol[U]]`, you are forcing the evaluation of `sol[U]` and hence of `NDSolve` with an unknown argument that should have a numerical value. This results in an error from `NDSolve`. Another way to notice this is to evaluate `sol[U]` on its own.

By removing `Evaluate`, `NDSolve` will evaluate only when called by `newhope`. Since a numerical value is now given (`newhope[t, 1]`) there is no more issue.